# what are the Hadoop requirements for hawq 2.4

Tags: hadoop, hawq, hdp

Using HAWQ 2.2 with HDP 2.5.3 on Centos 7.3.
Planing to upgrade to new HAWQ version 2.4.
What are the requirements for HAWQ 2.4?

Comment: I doubt there's any difference, but what HAWQ documentation have you found so far?

Comment: the last documentation is from Pivotal for HDB 2.3 (HAWQ 2.2)
https://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/230/hdb/index.html

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HAWQ/Build+and+Install#idKLNSXpld